# If $\mathbf{Ax}=\mu\mathbf y$ and $\mathbf{Ay}=\mu\mathbf x$, are $\mu$ or $-\mu$ an eigenvalue of $\mathbf A$?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Combining the two gives $\mathbf A^2\mathbf x = \mu^2\mathbf x$, but this does not necessarily imply that $\pm\mu$ are eigenvalues of $\mathbf A$ (rotation by $90^\circ$ in the plane comes to mind).

I appreciate any assistance with this.

Comment: Another way of doing this would be to extend $x$ and $y$ to a basis and consider the form of the matrix of $A$ with respect to that particular basis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Second Hint :
Try taking a look at $A\mathbf x + A\mathbf y$ and $A\mathbf x - A\mathbf y$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Matrix equations are the natural home of linear combinations of things ...